# ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished suddenly appearing

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I recently deployed my rails app on Heroku.  In the process I accidentally deleted my database.yml file.  I restored the file from the most recent copy in my git repository, however, now every time I try to log in to my development environment (on localhost:3000), it tells me:

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`.

I am using the mysql2 adapter and running ruby 1.8.7 on rails 3.0.9

I am confused because I believe I have restored my app to its exact state prior to deploying...

the development part of my database.yml file:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: thankfl_development
  pool: 5
  username: ------
  password: ------
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I can still access the database through the rails console, just not through the browser.

Any ideas what I could do?

Comment: Can you post the `.yml` file (with your usernames/passwords removed, obviously), and the command you're running that generates the error? Also, have you double-checked that the `.yml` file is actually up-to-date? Maybe a setting (such as a password) is out-of-date?

Comment: added the development part of my .yml file.  and yes the password is up-to-date.  as far as I can tell the only thing I did was remove the file, and add it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you restart your web server (webrick, thin, passenger, apache, or whatever), after restoring the `.yml` file? The database `.yml` file is read at startup, not on every request, so any changes/adds/removes involving that file require a web server restart, even in development mode.

That would explain why the console is working (since it loads the `database.yml` file when it opens), but your dev app doesn't.